# Drop down doesn't show up unless i change Nav height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

So I finally got my dropdown to work however unless i change the nav height here it won't show up:

```
header nav {
width:100%;
height:auto;
background:url(../images/menu-bg.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}
```

I've been playing with the Z value, but I'm not 100% sure how it works or if i missed something.  If i change the nav height to like 150px it works fine, but then there is a huge gap when the dropdown isn't there.

**HTML CODE:**

```
  <header>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1><a href="index.html">KB Customs</a></h1>
      <div class="fright">
      <div class="indent"> <span class="address">Walker, MI 49544</span>      <span class="phone">Tel: 616-901-1174</span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a  class="active"  href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="maintenance.html">Products </a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>
        <a href="maintenance.html">Products </a>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="repair.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="price.html">FAQ & Prices</a></li>
        <li><a href="locations.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
   </header>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
      /***** menu *****/

 header nav {
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 background:url(../images/menu-bg.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
z-index:1;
}

#page1 header nav {
margin-bottom:28px;
}

.menu li {
float:left;
position:relative;
background:url(../images/menu-spacer.gif) left top no-repeat;
z-index: 2;
}

.menu > li:first-child {
background:none;
}

.menu li a {
display:inline-block;
font-size:18px;
line-height:25px;
padding:12px 28px 12px 29px;
color:#808080;
text-transform:capitalize;
}

.menu > li:first-child > a {
text-indent:-999em;
background:url(../images/menu-home.png) center -25px no-repeat;
min-width:22px;
}

.menu li a.active, .menu > li > a:hover {
color:#fff;
}

 .menu > li:first-child > a.active, .menu > li:first-child > a:hover {
background-position:center 15px;
}


 ul li ul.dropdown{
    min-width:inherit; /* Set width of the dropdown */
    background:url(../images/menu-bg.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 0;
 }

ul li:hover ul.dropdown{
    display: block; /* Display the dropdown */
    color:#fff;
       z-index: 3;

 }

 ul li ul.dropdown li{
    display: block;
       z-index: 3;
 }

  ul li ul.dropdown:hover li a{
     color:#fff;
        z-index: 3;
 }
```

Comment: because of your `overflow:hidden;` in `header nav`, it's hidding a content that go out of you height.

Comment: Alright that was it...but when i remove that, then the background for the menu disappears.